# table view with search bar xcode

Tags: xcode, search, swift, tableview, segue

I am working on my one of my first  Swift projects based off this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view and want to be able to segue to different view controllers based on what table value I select ie selecting chocolate chips allows me to segue to one detail view controller which has a recipe for chocolate chip cookies, selecting jolly ranchers allows me to link to a recipe for jolly ranchers etc

Answer (score 0):

use the prepareForSeque function, prepare whatever you want before going to the destination View